# how to add back percentage of a numeric value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this code

`update users 
set reg_balance = reg_balance + 10% reg_balance
WHERE reg_level = '4'`

Here I want to add back 10% of reg_balance

let's assume that the current value of reg_balance is 1000, running this code will add 100 to 1000 making it 1100 which is the +10% of 1000.

Comment: Multiply the original balance by 1.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below mysql query:

```
UPDATE users 
set reg_balance = (round(((reg_balance * 10) / 100 ), 2) + reg_balance)
WHERE reg_level = '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 update users set reg_balance = reg_balance +(reg_balance/10) WHERE reg_level = '4';
```

this will work all the cases, if reg_balance accept float values. Might be this will throw error `reg_balance` as int and `reg_balance +(reg_balance/10)` return float data.